# How to order a result set of @Entities by the size of an @ElementCollection?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, sql-order-by

I am using Spring Boot (2.1.6) and Hibernate in a project and I am familiar with the basic concepts of OR mapping. However, a simple "ORDER BY" problem already brings me to the boundaries of my understanding and I hope that you folks can help me clear this up.

For now, assume that I have the following entity `MyEntity` defined in my project.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    public long id;

    ...

    @ElementCollection
    public Set<String> labels = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I also have a `JPARepository<MyEntity>` and regular CRUD queries work perfectly.

In Spring, any `JPARepository` can be queried for paged results using a `PageRequest`. The `PageRequest` allows to define the `page`, `size`, and sorting criterion for the page, simply by indicating the field by which the results should be sorted. For example:

```
int page = 1;
int size = 100;
Sort sortBy = Sort.by(Direction.DESC, "id");
Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(page, size, sortBy);

Page<MyEntity> pagedResults = repo.findAll(paging);
```

This out-of-the-box functionality only works for fields of `MyEntity` though. In my case, I would like to sort the result set by the number of labels stored in each record. I know that I can always add a custom `@Query` to my repository definition, but I am wondering whether there is a cleaner way to achieve this.

My initial thinking was that I could easily create a "transient" column without backing field that could be used for the sorting, like:

```
// added to MyEntity
@Column(name = "numLabels")
public String getNumLabels() {
    return labels.size();
}
```

However, the `@Column` annotation gets ignored unless I also have a corresponding field, which is then always `NULL` though.

I then tried to write a custom `@Query` and discovered that HQL offers the `size(..)` operator that can be used for exactly this.

```
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
    ...
    @Query("SELECT e FROM MyEntity e ORDER BY size(e.labels) ASC")
    List<MyEntity> findMyEntityOrderedByNumLabelsAsc();
}
```

This would require the definition of two query versions though to support both `ASC` and `DESC`. I know that I could also add a `Pageable` parameter to the definition, but when I use `Sort.by(ASC, "size(e.labels)")` to mimick this query style, the execution crashes stating that no property with such a name can be found.

So, bottom line, I have two questions:

1) What is the easiest, cleanest, or most-canonical way to sort result sets of `MyEntity` in a Spring Boot `JPARepository` by the number of labels stored in it?

2) I do not understand why my `@Column` annotation gets ignored. I am not sure whether such a "one way serialization" would actually solve 1), but I would still like to know whether this is possible somehow. While minimizing the redundant information in the Java object, storing it in the database would significantly simplify data analyses in other programming languages that only consume the data. They do not have to implement the logic of `getNumLabels` again (which is trivial in this case, but you can easily imagine a case with a more complicated logic).